# Which diference are between のように and みたい

Tags: grammar, word-choice

For example:

> - 犬のように
> - 犬みたい

Or:

> - 子供のように歌ってください
> - 子供みたいに歌ってください

There is only one similar question to this one in this website but the answer is incomplete. Please help me with this!

Comment: Just keep in mind that the you wanna actually know is the difference between のよう and みたい, the に is a particle that can be attached to either one of them, depending on your sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a major difference in meaning between ～みたい(に) and ～のよう(に).
～みたい(だ、に、な、etc.) sounds more casual and ～(の)よう(だ、に、な、etc.) sounds more formal.

Examples*:
「火**みたいに**熱い」「火**のように**熱い」（比況）
「もう勝った**みたいな**ものだ」「もう勝った**ような**ものだ」（比況）
「彼**みたいな**優秀な人材はいない」「彼**のような**優秀な人材はいない」（例示）
「どうやら電車が遅れている**みたいだ**」「どうやら電車が遅れている**ようだ**」（不確かな断定）
「少し味が薄い**みたいだ**」「少し味が薄い**ようだ**」（婉曲）
-- the former versions sound more casual than the latter ones.

So 子供**のように**歌ってください sounds less casual and more formal than 子供**みたいに**歌ってください, though they have the same meaning.

<sub>(*例文は明鏡国語辞典を参考にしました）</sub>

---

<sub>As a side note, ～ように cannot be replaced with ～みたいに when used in the sense of "so that~~"(目的), "May~~!"(optative/祈願), "as (you know / stated below...)"(前置き), or as part of expressions 「Verb+ようになる」,「Verb+ようにする」. Examples*:</sub>

<sub>「よく見える**ように**高く掲げる」（×みたいに）（目的）

「どうか入学できます**ように**」（×みたいに）（祈願）

「ご存じ**のように**」「先にお知らせしました**ように**」「以下**のように**」（×みたいに）（前置き）

「英語が話せる**ように**なる」（×みたいになる）

「彼とはもう二度と会わない**ように**した」(×みたいにした)</sub>

<sub>(*例文は明鏡国語辞典から引用しました)</sub>

Answer (score 5):

～のように = "in the manner of"
みたい = "appearing like"

If you think of these phrases when reading these, you'll be able to make a clearer distinction. However, in terms of selecting which to use in a sentence, there is some overlap.